# Std::map \ std::set contain duplicate keys

Tags: c++, std, stdmap, stdset

I have an issue and though I understand, that is kind of a stupid question to ask, but I failed to find a solution on my own.

So, I'm trying to accumulate a container with unique values of a structure I have.

```
struct Symbol {
    D2D1_RECT_F bbox;
    wchar_t data;
    fz_font_s* font;
    float color[4];
};
```

What I'm doing is trying to use `std::map` and `std::set`. Being aware, that I need to provide a predicate in order to give container a way to determine the order. What I have is:

```
struct SymbolCmp {
    bool operator() (const Symbol& lhs, const Symbol& rhs) const
    {
        auto errorHandler = (lhs.bbox.top == rhs.bbox.top) ? (lhs.bbox.left < rhs.bbox.left) : lhs.bbox.top < rhs.bbox.top;

        if (lhs.data == rhs.data &&
            lhs.font != rhs.font) {
            return errorHandler;
        }

        float lArea = (lhs.bbox.bottom - lhs.bbox.top) *
            (lhs.bbox.right - lhs.bbox.left);
        float rArea = (rhs.bbox.bottom - rhs.bbox.top) *
            (rhs.bbox.right - rhs.bbox.left);

        auto relative = (lArea / rArea < 0.95f ||
            lArea / rArea > 1.05f);

        return (lhs.data == rhs.data) ? relative && errorHandler : (lhs.data < rhs.data);
    }
};
```

And then I just try inserting values inside of `std::set<Symbol, SymbolCmp>` and `std::map<Symbol, byte, SymbolCmp>`.

Sadly enough the results are frustrating, cause what I get is pretty far from an object, containing unique keys only. Most of Symbol's have duplicates.

So I REALLY to understand, what I'm missing?

Comment: Have you checked the return-value of `SymbolCmp(a,b)` and `SymbolCmp(b,a)` with two `Symbol`s a and b that should compare equal?

Comment: Didn't look very closely, but it appears to me that `SymbolCmp` doesn't satisfy [strict-weak ordering](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html). Hint: Does it still happen if `relative` is always `true`?

Comment: A strict-weak ordering is required.  Can you guarantee that with all of that code you've written?  Just the usage of floating point itself to determine order is suspicious.

Comment: @MohitJain
Well, from the tests i've made, i'm pretty positive about the order.

Comment: The way you compare objects seems too complicated to me. You should think about what it depicts; maybe there is a simpler way. One source of error might be `bbox`: is it normalized? Did you try to debug two "equal" objects?

Answer (score 2):

Your predicate doesn't ensure strict-weak ordering. Following should work:

```
struct SymbolCmp {
    bool operator() (const Symbol& lhs, const Symbol& rhs) const
    {
        if(lhs.data == rhs.data) {
            return (lhs.bbox.top == rhs.bbox.top) ? (lhs.bbox.left < rhs.bbox.left) : lhs.bbox.top < rhs.bbox.top;
        } else {
            return lhs.data < rhs.data;
        }
    }
};
```

If you want to use `font`, `color` and dimension in the logic, ensure that your follow the strict-weak ordering constraint.

Comment: Could you please explain, what is wrong with strict-weak ordering in my predicate? I mean, in what case it will fail to provide the order?

Comment: @AleksandrKurinnoi If there are 3 classes A, B and C such that A.font = B.font and there areas are almost same, you may get false for A < B and B < C but true for A < C.